# How to add comment in h:panelGrid without causing it to generate empty TD

Tags: jsf-2, facelets

I've found that if I add comment inside panelgrid tag, it will generate an empty `<td>` for it. I've found this link about this issue:  https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1768.  According to this link, it is not a bug and marked as WONTFIX.  In the link, someone has provided these workarounds, I wonder if there are better solutions than these:

1. Let Facelets ignore all comments, if you do not want to keep them at all. There is a `javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS` switch for that in `web.xml`.
2. Move the comment into the `<h:panelGroup>`, if you want to keep them.
3. Use `<ui:remove><!-- first column --></ui:remove>`, you could then also ignore the XML comment-style and come up with something fancier.

Comment: That's pretty much it. As to choosing the one or the other, what do *you* feel most comfortable with? What's for *you* the most easy and best maintainable? Pick that.

Comment: Thanks BalusC.  Since I'm converting from jsf1.2 to jsf 2.0, easier would be option 1.  Sounded crazy to mark such as wontfix...